# SQL Join tablese multiple times on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I've got two tables:

```
personal
____________
| id | name |
| 15 | Mike |
| 23 | Rich |
| 35 | Hugo |
```

and

```
events
___________________________
| id | driver | translator |
| 22 | 15     | 23         |
| 23 | 35     | 35         |
```

is there a way to join these two tables to get something like

```
events

___________________________________
| id | driverName | translatorName |
| 22 | Mike       | Rich           |
| 23 | Hugo       | Hugo           |
```

thx

Comment: Please make an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT 
  e.id
  ,p1.name driverName
  ,p2.name translatorName 
  FROM `events` e
  JOIN `personal` p1
    ON p1.id=e.driver
  JOIN `personal` p2
    ON p2.id=e.translator
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
select e.id, (select name from Personal where id = e.driver) as DiverName, 
       p.name as TranslatorName
from Personal p
inner join [events] e on p.id = e.translator
```